# Powershell script to get user by email

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm try to write a script which get user by email address, i need so it doest matter if email is upper case or lower case

i have wrote this but its not showing any account.

```
$ADemail = "email-address@domain.co.uk"
$aduser = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property SamAccountName, EmailAddress
foreach($user in $aduser)
{
    $email = $user.EmailAddress
    if ( $email -ne $null -and $email.ToLower() -eq $ADemail.ToLower() )
    {
        $user.SamAccountName
        $user.emailaddress
    }
}
```

Comment: The calls to `ToLower()` are unnecessary, since `-eq` is case-insensitive by default.  You need to use `-ceq` to get case-sensitive comparisons.  Comparing to `$null` is then not needed as you won't potentially be calling a method on a null object.  For testing, I'd suggest you print out `$user.EmailAddress` to make sure it is returning something, and is in the expected format.

Comment: I did do this and I can see all of the account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your "IF" statement is wrong... I think the IF is trying to say if $email is not null, convert it to lower case and see if it is equal to $ADemail?

Try this?

```
if (($email -eq $null) -or ($email -eq ""))
{
    # skip
} else
{
    if ($email.ToLower() -eq $ADemail.ToLower() )
    {
        # write out results
    }
}
```

My other observations is this is a very in-efficient way to get the answer you are looking for - I would suggest using get-aduser with `-filter` to get the AD server to do all the filtering for you rather than doing it locally. Something like `Get-ADUser -Filter { mail -Like $ADemail} -Properties mail` (haven't tested that!). Also worth noting is that this will only work if the address you are searching for is actually in the `mail` attribute - it might also be one of the proxy addresses... but that's a whole other problem! (Ref on proxy addresses: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0690df24-4504-4347-80c8-6985d1fa8e11/get-samaccountname-from-email?forum=winserverpowershell )

Comment: This code work. Thank you. I did try this Get-ADUser -Filter {emailaddress -like $ADemail} -Property SamAccountName, EmailAddress but it ddint work but now i try it again and it work. i do agree having code like this Get-ADUser -Filter {emailaddress -like $ADemail} -Property SamAccountName, EmailAddress is much better